# Android: Should I use a ListView? (case: list elements with partially unknown structure)

Tags: android, listview, android-layout, android-listview, convertview

#### Assumptions about the list (updated):

- <s>It will *not* contain more than ***10 list elements*** (the list elements are defined by the xml layout below).</s>
- The height of every element is unknown, because the list element contain a `LinearLayout` that can have up to ***20 child views*** (see xml below).

#### XML Layout of the list element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation:"horizontal">

    <!--
        This LinearLayout is going to contain one or more 
        Views which will be added progammatically on runtime.
        The number of children views added to it depend on the 
        data to be displayed, and the only assumption that can 
        be made is that there's will be no more than 20 child 
        views for one particular instance of this LinearLayout.
    -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-25dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

#### Questions:

- Does it make any sense to use a `ListView` for a layout that has such freedom 
  in its structure (like the one above), and still being able to make use of the
  convertView as passed in to the `ListView#getView(...)`?
- As an alternative, would it be wrong to put all the list elements in an outer
  `LinearLayout` and put this within a `ScrollView`? By doing this, I wouldn't get
  caching abilities of the `ListView`, but maybe it wouldn't be so heavy given the 
  assumptions about the list? (see top). *(Any pointers on how to make this alternative look and feel like a `ListView`? I'm thinking of applying standard colors and selectors etc.)*

Comment: When I tried to construct a view dynamically by adding views/removing them, the listview threw an expception. So not sure you could do what you want i.e. dynamically add views, when you are trying to recycle the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know some of your 10 elemets will be the same, you could use

[getItemViewType(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29)

To be sure that the convertView will match your item type convertView

Comment: Differentiating on view types turned out to be the most efficient approach in my particular case. It made it possible to keep the view hierarchy small :)